# C++ - Template with class function reference doesn’t compile on Android

Tags: android, c++, ios, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

I'm currently trying to get a kind of special template to work. This is a very minimal example to show exactly what's going wrong.
Here's the Template:

```
template <typename ClassT,  int (ClassT::*Func)() const>
class TEST
{
public:
    TEST(ClassT const * selfVar) : _this(selfVar) {
    }

private:
    ClassT const* _this;
    };
```

This code is the Entity.h file of my project:

```
int _a;
int getA() const {
    return _a;
}

TEST<TestClass, &TestClass::getA> test = TEST<TestClass, &TestClass::getA>(this);
```

The code compiles fine for iOS with Xcode but does not for Android with the following errors. It's no option to do the initializing in the constructor - I know that works, but I need this to be one-liners in the .h file.

This is the error log:

```
jni/../../Classes/Entity.h:37:54: warning: extra qualification 'Entity::' on member 'getA' [-fpermissive]
 TEST<Entity, &Entity::getA> yoyo = TEST<Entity, &Entity::getA>();
                                                  ^
jni/../../Classes/Entity.h:37:62: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration
 TEST<Entity, &Entity::getA> yoyo = TEST<Entity, &Entity::getA>();
                                                          ^
jni/../../Classes/Entity.h:37:62: error: 'TEST<Entity, &Entity::getA>& Entity::getA' conflicts with a previous declaration
jni/../../Classes/Entity.h:29:9: note: previous declaration 'int Entity::getA() const'
 int getA() const {
     ^
jni/../../Classes/Entity.h:37:66: error: expected unqualified-id before '>' token
 TEST<Entity, &Entity::getA> yoyo = TEST<Entity, &Entity::getA>();
                                                              ^
jni/../../Classes/Entity.h:37:45: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)
 TEST<Entity, &Entity::getA> yoyo = TEST<Entity, &Entity::getA>();
                                         ^
```

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but the default constructor of TEST will be called automatically, there is no need in `= …`. Simple `TEST<Entity, &Entity::getA> test;` works for  me (if you wrap **Entity.h** with `struct Entity {…};`

Comment: In this minimal example you are right, the default constructor is not enough for my case. I edited the sample code. Do you also have an idea how to solve this case?

Comment: `TEST<TestClass, &TestClass::getA> test (this);` may also use `{this}`

Answer (score 0):

```
template <typename ClassT,  int (ClassT::*Func)() const>
class TEST
{
public:
    TEST(ClassT const * selfVar) : _this(selfVar) {
    }

private:
    ClassT const* _this;
};

struct Entity {
    int _a;
    int getA() const {
        return _a;
    }
};

class TestClass: public Entity {
    void method() {
        TEST<Entity, &Entity::getA> test(this);
    }
};
```